# Why did Thanos do that at the end?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In Infinity War, Thanos implies that the reason that he wants to kill half of all life is because life generally grows beyond its means. That is, if too many people are alive, then their will go beyond what their natural resources can comfortably maintain.

However, it is clearly stated that once he has the completed Infinity Gauntlet he is the most powerful being in the universe. Shouldn't he be able to just create more natural resources.

Why doesn't he just use his massive power to fix the problems that made him want to kill half the universe?

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't he just use his massive power to fix the problems that
>   made him want to kill half the universe?

This is because he is trying to impress Death.  He is in love with Death (death appeared as a female to Thanos) and he is trying to win her favor.

> Growing in power and infamy as he traveled the universe, Thanos once
>   met Death itself, as it appeared to him embodied in a female form.
>   Thanos was infatuated with the being, and endeavored to make himself
>   worthy in order to earn her love in return.

Check out this reference for more details:  [Marvel Universe Thanos](http://marvel.com/universe/Thanos#axzz5EYSVMq7q)

Comment: This is only true for the comics. As far as we know, in MCU, there is no reference to Death at all. In the movie, his only motivation is to avoid suffer in other planets as he had experienced in his own planet.

Comment: @Zanon Doesn't Thanos indicate his motivations are to court Death in the bonus end-credit scene in the first Avengers movie?  He didn't say anything but IIRC he smiled or something.

Comment: @user1717828 "To challenge them [humans] is to court death", his smile was surely a reference to the comics, but if you consider only the movies material, you can't say that Thanos killed half of the universe to impress Death.

Comment: @Zanon ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I guess we'll have to wait for the sequel.

Comment: I think the apparition of Gamora seen at the end in a cutscene is Death.  That would make her question, "What did it cost you?" make a little more sense.

Comment: We have seen the Goddess Of Death in the MCU: Hela